# Alert when Azure function fails to initialize

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-monitoring

I have an Azure function, which fails while running Startup.cs (while initializing the runtime) because it can't load a key from a Key vault. I would like to automate the deployment of this function in the future and therefore I would like to set up an alert to trigger if the function can't initialize correctly for any reason. (I can fix this speficic error, I just use it as an example).

At the moment I see the error in the *Notifications* section of the function page in the Azure portal:
[image: Notifications]

I also see the exceptions in *Diagnose and solve problems* -> *Availability and Performance*:
[image: Availability and Performance]

But I can't seem to find a way to set up an alert to respond to this situation. I assumed that Resource health alert would cover this, but it doesn't. Maybe because to portal reports the function as Status: *Running*. I also can't find this error in Application Insights.

Is there any way to set up this alert?

Answer (score 1):

To create the Alerts for Function App Runtime failures, start with the *Alert Action Groups*.

Open your function app in the Azure Portal and create the action group that points to your function and email configuration:

[image]

[image]

In the same function app menu > Logs > Get the Function Request Failure results such as below:
[image]

Then, click on “New Alert Rule” > Insert the values for Alert logic such as Frequency of Evaluation, Operator, Threshold Value, Measure of data summary, etc.,

- Next, Select the Action Group which is created at the starting - that contains the Selected Function Data and the Email Notification configuration details:

[image]

[image]

After configuring the alert group, you’ll get the mail that the alerts are mailed accordingly:
[image]

I have given the wrong input to get the alert for the Function Runtime failure, which is driven to the Alerts:
**Result**:

[image]

[image]

For more details regarding Azure Alerts, refer to this [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-create-new-alert-rule?tabs=metric).

#### Updated Answer:

[image] - This query gives the function errors messages in the logs and from this panel we can create the alert rule for the errors and warnings.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain the situation clearly, but this solution doesn't work. The query that you use doesn't return any values. I think this would work, if the function failed during request processing. But it fails during initiation and it never gets a chance to do any processing.

Comment: While running the function in the cloud (Azure Portal), the function initialization starts when we hit the function URl. That information shows in the log panel like Function host initialized, started, etc all those logs comes under Runtime Failure. That gives you alert like your function is not initialized or failed to start due to some error before request processing.

Comment: That is not exactly true. First of all, the errors logged in *Diagnose and solve problems* are often triggered by opening the function detail in portal, not calling it directly. The runtime seems to be trying to initialize in this case as well. 
Either way, the query, that you suggested, doesn't return anything even when I try to call the function. I get response "Function host is not running.", but nothing seems to be logged in Insights, even when host.json sets logging to "Debug".

Comment: `Traces` query gives all statuses of function app including errors and warnings. Please check the updated answer. Do let me know if any information is required.

Comment: That is interesting. It sounds like it should work, but for some reason there seems to be a gap during the initiation, where the errors aren't logged. Unfortunately, for my issue the Traces are empty :(

Comment: I removed my down vote, because this solution will likely cover part of the potential breaking scenarios. It unfortunately doesn't work for my situation.